# How do i synchronize an entity after saving a child object to the database?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a User object that gets loaded from the database during user login. This user has a OneToMany relationship (messageList) with the Message entity. When another user sends a new message to that user this message is stored in the database. After that has happened I need to have the messageList of the logged in user to be synchronized automatically with the Database. In other words, the new message needs to appear in the messageList list of the receiving user.

Is there a Spring-data way of accomplishing this? I prefer not to refresh the entire userEntity after the message has been saved. (Using entitymanager.refresh()) because it seems like overkill to retrieve all the child objects inside the userEntity just for the sake of synchronizing the messageList.

I could add the new message to the userEntity and then save the userEntity, but sometimes the same message gets sent to multiple users and I don't want to have to retrieve all the user object just to be able to save a message.

The solution I currently have is to make a Spring AspectJ listener method that listens to all methods saving a message. When that happens the save message gets manually added to the concerning user entity messageList. Why all this effort you may ask? Because I want the message to automatically appear in the frontend (I'm using Angular 4 framework). Angular 4 listens for changes in the data model.

But before I implement this solution I was wondering whether there is a more simpler way of achieving messagelist synchronization.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is that you consider the `Message`s to be part of the `User`. From your description it seems the `User` consists of more or less static information, while `Message`s appear often.

So I propose to change the domain model to have `Message` as a separate Aggregate Root with its own repository. The repository should probably have a method to get all the `Message`s for a `User` and maybe another one for getting all the messages that happened for a `User` after a certain timestamp or a different `Message` allowing you to get just the new `Message`s.

Another question is, if you are using the correct technology for the job. Distributing events via relational database is possible but they aren't exactly build for this. You might want to consider alternatives like an in memory store (e.g. Hazelcast) or a dedicated messaging solution (e.g. RabbitMQ). Note that the `Message`s can (and possibly should) still be saved in a persistent store, but not to use that store for distributing it.

Comment: user isen't just static information, and Message already has its own repository, but thanks for the information. RabbitMQ looks very interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

I will have to use websockets in order to achieve what I want. Since i'm using Spring in my project I will use the Spring websocket module for this.